# adding a leading and trailing space in wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this bit of code:

```
<ul class="login-links">
    <li>
        <a href="/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" class="simplemodal-login"><?php printf(__("Login"))?></a>
        <span id="space-login-string"><?php printf(__(" or "));?></span>
        <a href="/wp-login.php?action=register" class="simplemodal-register"><?php printf(__("Register"))?></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It is a part of a sentence which has to be translated by WPML.
It should look like this: LOGIN OR REGISTER

Does anyone know why the leading and trailing space is trimmed and therefor looks like this: LOGINORREGISTER

It has to be something simple but, stupid me, I can't find it. Please help.

Comment: `<?php printf( __( "&nbsp;or&nbsp;" ) ); ?>`? But I don't understand why the spaces need to be there at all in the translated string...Why not just put a space after `LOGIN` and before `REGISTER` and then just translate the `"or"` without spaces?

Comment: Same problem occurs then at the beginning of the word Register. All three itmes are part of a composed string. Login is a link and translatable, "or" is just a word and has to be translatable, Register is also a link and has to be translatable. See in the comments below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities:

1. The function `__()` might trim the output or input on its own.
2. The spaces are missing in the translated string.

IMHO, the spaces should not be inside the string which is to be translated, since only "or" needs a translation and making sure that the spaces are inserted is not the translators job.

**Edit:** As it turned out, the problem was that the three elements Login, or, and Register are floated left. This causes the spaces to be ignored.

To keep the spaces while keeping the three elements in one line, give all three elements `display: inline;` *instead* of the floating.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. 1.) Possible. but the echo _e() behaves in the same way. 2) It is not only missed in the translated (Dutch) string but also in the sites native English. Even in the HTML output. I will try to lift the spaces out of printf__() function en see what happens then. I will be back.

Comment: Lifting the spaces and add them in a different fashion didn't give me the expected result. For now I solved it using css: wrapped it in a span with an ID and then adding left an right margin to the span.

Comment: If the spaces even disappear if you put them directly in the HTML, something is really wrong. Can you post a little more code?

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. Here is the complete line of code: `<ul class="login-links">
                                <li><a href="/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" class="simplemodal-login"><?php printf(__("Login"))?></a>
                                    <span id="space-login-string"><?php printf(__("or"));?></span> <a href="/wp-login.php?action=register" class="simplemodal-register"><?php printf(__("Register"))?></a></li>
                            </ul>` Maybe it will help.

Comment: Next time you should edit it into your original question. However, this looks okay to me, so my guess would be some css-floating going on there which nullifies the spaces.

Comment: About editting -> ok. It is true the items are floating left. When not floating left all three items (Login, or, register) are on their own separate line in the UI. I'm gonna test it.

Comment: That is the problem: do not float them but use `display: inline;` instead, that will keep all three elements in one line but keep the spaces intact!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70053/discussion-between-lars-ebert-and-a3o).

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to the [I18n for WordPress Developers docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Placeholders). The right way of doing this with `printf()` would be:

```
printf( __( 'LOGIN %d REGISTER.', 'your-text-domain' ), 'or' );
```

There are a lot of other ways you could also do it, such as using `_e()` or `__()`.

Comment: @mevius, thank you for your answer. In the comments with the answer below I added the complete line of code. Maybe it make things a bit clear. The words Login or Register ar coming from translatable links. I did not know another way to get this working.